How to change code on Alexa Widget example?
I was trying to build my own Alexa widget and found this nice tutorial.
Everythink worked fine up to the point I changed something in the code which was not visible in preview.
First I wanted an own text to use it in the widget so I added in index.js helloWorld to the PlantCareIntentHandler:
handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .addDirective({
                    type: "Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument",
                    document: plantCareDocument,
                    datasources: {
                        alexaPhotoData: {
                            title: "Plant Care Reminder",
                            backgroundImage: {
                                sources: [
                                    {
                                        url: "https://d2o906d8ln7ui1.cloudfront.net/images/templates_v3/long_text/LongTextSampleBackground_Dark.png",
                                        size: "large"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            lastWateredDate: attributes.date || "",
                            primaryText: "Haworthia Zebra Plant",
                            secondaryText: "Water today",
                            buttonText: "I watered my plant",
                            helloWorld: "Hello World!"
                        }
                    }
                }
                )

And in plant_care.json I changed a text using my helloWorld instead of original:
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Text",
                  "style": "textStyleDisplay5",
                  "text": "${alexaPhotoData.helloWorld}"
                },
                ...
              ]

I clicked on "Save" and then "Deploy" and waited until deployment was finished. I went back to Build > Multimodal Responses > Widget > Edit but nothing changed. I found the "DATA"-Tab but my data helloWorld was not there. So I thought to just change the primaryText in alexaPhotoData and did the steps again but also this was not working.
Did I missed a step or something else?
